# Appending a package to Ubuntu ISO

Tags: iso, teamviewer, kickstart

I am trying to include a package to an ubuntu ISO. I have googled and found some solutions with kickstart. But, I dont want to automate the partitioning and all. I wish it to appear like a normal installation and it should list team viewer after OS is installed. Is it possible?

Update : I dont mean to edit a Live CD. I mean the installation disk. The package must  be installed along with the OS and not live CD

Comment: Hi Karel. I mean customizing install ISO and not editing LIVE CD contents

Comment: The Ubuntu live DVD is exactly the same thing as the install ISO. To prove it you can make an ordinary install ISO and boot it without installing Ubuntu. In case you didn't know it, you can try Ubuntu without installing it from the Ubuntu install ISO and run it as an Ubuntu live DVD.

Comment: Oh sounds good then. I will try this and update you shortly.

Comment: Is this still working? I am unable to locate the package in that repo and it seems like the project is discontinued

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder

Comment: https://launchpad.net/~kamilion/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntu-builder

Comment: Hi Karel...ur comment was a lifesaver. The new ISO is falling to text mode by default. if we enter startx, no task bar is there. also, just a plain desktop is coming after installation

Comment: I have prepared an answer to your comment that I haven't posted anywhere yet except for at Ubuntu Pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11895151/

Comment: Thanks. Anyhow, I think ubuntu builder is not uptodate. Not working properly for ubuntu 14. I followed official ubuntu documentation of ISO customization and it worked. Thanks a lot Karel for your time.